# How do I force an iPod to display the 10-key style virtual keyboard with a decimal key in an HTML input tag?

Tags: html, ios, ipod, virtual-keyboard

Setting the inputmode worked for iPhone, but didn't work on iPods. I've managed to get the iPod to show the 10-key style keyboard once while doing a pattern = "\d*", but couldn't figure out a way to get it to add in the decimal point.

Please and thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Please add a code sample of what you have done so far

Comment: I've done a variety of things, so there isn't really one copyable line. As mentioned, it's an input tag. It always has type="number" I'll try to quickly list a few attributes I've tried from memory. inputmode = "number", inputmode="decimal", step = ".01", pattern = "\d*", pattern = "\d*\.\d*" I've tried various combinations of steps and inputmodes or patterns and inputmodes as well.